# .htaccess - rewrite with https and trailing / in one step has unintended conseqences

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I added an ssl certificate to my website recently using cloudflare. I added some lines to my .htaccess to use https by default. Looking at google page speed insights, I notice that when visiting a sub-directory of my website using http, three redirects were occurring. For example the following redirect chain would occur when visiting http://markfisher.photo/galleries.

1. [http://markfisher.photo/galleries](https://markfisher.photo/galleries)
2. https:://markfisher.photo/galleries (Sorry, not enough rep for >2 links. Double colon is to break link)
3. http:://markfisher.photo/galleries/
4. https:://markfisher.photo/galleries/

I fixed this (i.e. combining the https and trailing slash in one step) by modifying the relevant lines in .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^markfisher.photo$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.markfisher.photo$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}\/ [L,R]
```

The only change from before was adding / towards the end of the bottom line. This works as intended for subdirectories of my website, but when visiting the root directory with http http:://markfisher.photo, it gets redirected to https:://markfisher.photo//. This works fine but looks ugly. I can't work out how to stop the double trailing slashes from occuring. I'm guessing it has something to do with a global .htaccess file used by my host but I don't know what that file(s) might contain so I'm struggling to work it out.

Also if anyone could tell my how to get www in there as will without any additional redirects that would be great.

Comment: The request URI for your root folder is `/`, and you add an additional `/` after that. And it would happen for your directories too, if those were to be requested via HTTP and with a trailing slash attached already.

Comment: So is there a RewriteCond I can use to target the root folder only, and apply a RewriteRule for that.? If that's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked. I separated into 2 cases - one where the trailing slash was absent and needed to be rewritten in, and on where it was present and so an extra slash was unwanted.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^markfisher.photo$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.markfisher.photo$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.*/$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.markfisher.photo%{REQUEST_URI}\/ [R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^markfisher.photo$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.markfisher.photo$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.markfisher.photo%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```